# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_hold'

Tags: numpy, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using numpy and matplotlib in Python3.
The following code is causing the error:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.axes import Subplot as plt
from matplotlib import pylab


 a=[1,1]
 b=[1,1]
 fsam = 48000         
 w, h = freqz(b, a, worN=2000)
 plt.plot(((fsam-8000) * 0.5 / np.pi) * w, abs(h), label=" ")
```

The actual error with matplotlib 1.3.x:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py3.2-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4119, in plot   
     if not self._hold:   
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_hold'
```

The actual error with matplotlib 1.2.0:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   
   File "/home/christoph/audio_measurement/AudioTools/AudioTools.py", line 222, in <module>   
       main()   
     File "/home/christoph/audio_measurement/AudioTools/AudioTools.py", line 216, in main   
       form = AppForm()   
     File "/home/christoph/audio_measurement/AudioTools/AudioTools.py", line 39, in __init__   
       self.on_draw()   
     File "/home/christoph/audio_measurement/AudioTools/AudioTools.py", line 80, in on_draw   
       self.transfer = Transfer(self.canvas)   
     File "/home/christoph/audio_measurement/AudioTools/Transfer.py", line 42, in __init__   
       plt.plot(((fsam-8000) * 0.5 / np.pi) * w, abs(h), label=" ")   
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 3995, in plot   
       if not self._hold: self.cla()   
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_hold'
```

Transfer is the class, which plots onto the canvas.

I had a look at the length of the coefficients a and b, but they did not effect the result.
I could not find anything on that. Does anyone know whats going wrong?

Comment: not yet, will do and report back...

Comment: similar result for matplotlib 1.2.0

Comment: `>>> from matplotlib import axes, figure`   
    `>>> print(type(axes.Axes(figure.Figure(), [0]*4)))`   
    `<class 'matplotlib.axes.Axes'>`

Comment: with `print(str(plt.gca()), type(plt.gca()))` i have the error `File "/home/christoph/audio_measurement/AudioTools/Transfer.py", line 59, in __init__     self.figure.Axes.get_xaxis(self.transfer).set_visible(False)   
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'Axes'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'd use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` with `plt.plot`, `plt.subplot`, `plt.show`, etc  -- or even just `from pylab import *`. Anyway, this line

```
from matplotlib.axes import Subplot as plt
```

is the reason you have an unbound `plot` function that's trying to operate on the `ndarray` argument. `Subplot` needs to be instantiated.  This should work:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import freqz

import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.axes import Subplot

fig = Figure()
ax = Subplot(fig, 111)
fig.add_subplot(ax)
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)

a=[1,1]
b=[1,1]
fsam = 48000         
w, h = freqz(b, a, worN=2000)

ax.plot(((fsam-8000) * 0.5 / np.pi) * w, abs(h), label=" ")
canvas.show()
```